# build email notification sytem that send emails on sql server triggers

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, email, amazon-web-services

I have a web project which is written in C# and uses SQL Server. I need to write an email notification system. I did some research and some people suggest to use CLR and some suggest to the business logic in C# code. I haven't done this system before and I want to know how other people do it.

What I have in my mind is to create a `Queue` table and and triggers for the tables I want to watch for changes. When the trigger is executed, it will insert an email request to the `Queue` table. Later, I will loop that queue table and send emails. I might be using Amazon web services to send emails in near future but not decided yet.

Do you think this is a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good idea, but wave you looked at what's already there, out-of the box? [`sp_send_dbmail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) does pretty much the same. It puts the mail request in a queue and uses an external application to do the SMTP stuff. I reckon that if you must use Amazon SNS then the built-in Database Mail will not work.

Do not listen to advice that recommends sending the email directly from trigger (eg. using SQLCLR). Beside the obvious performance hit (every DML operation on the table now has to wait for the huge latency of a SMTP or HTTP operation) you have the much bigger problem of transactional consistency, how do you recall the email on rollback? So yes, using an intermediate queue is mandatory. Also have a look at [Using Tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/).